# Apache virtual host resulting in 403

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtual

I am using wamp on windows 7. I have had no issues until I installed zend and set up a virtual host. I am getting a 403 when trying to access my local host now.

In my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/path to project"
   ServerName .local
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

  <Directory "C:/wamp/path to project">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my httpd.conf:

Listen 80

The path to the project is read, write, modify.

As far as I can tell I have the virtual host configured correctly yet I am getting 403s.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: And how about FS (filesystem) permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in your `httpd.conf` there is `AllowOverride None` set for your `c:/wamp/` directory, which is why you can't change it.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the issue. I commented out the AllowOveride None in my httpd.conf and presto everything works.